# Label or id of header

Tags: mediawiki

There is some header on some article page:

```
==some header==
```

Let's say that I want to place some link to this header:

```
[[article#some header|go to header]]
```

However, one time I would like to change title of "some header", so my link becomes invalid. Is there some way to connect header title with some label or id? For example:

```
==some header|ID==
```

and then I write in link something like:

```
[[article#ID|go to header]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like

```
==some header==
<a id="ID" />
```

This is how Wikipedia does it, see [Template:Anchor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aAnchor).